# Regex: Group needs to stop at first occurence

Tags: regex

I'm not good at writing regex queries (I'm a google copy/paste regex-er :) ), but it works for most search results.  I'm using the regex output in splunk searches, so this might need some adaptation sometimes.
Currently I'm having the following issue, and I don't know why it happens, and how to solve it:

*raw search result:*

`Identity "mailboxname" -User "mailboxalias" -AccessRights ("FullAccess")</Data><Data>domain.fqdn/OU1/OU2/Display Name User</Data><Data>S-1-x-11111-1111-2222-2222</Data><Data>S-1-x-3333-4444-5555</Data>`

*regex query with group result:*

`(?m)domain.fqdn/OU1/OU2/(?<Affected_Mailbox>.+)\</Data><Data>S-`

So I would assume my "Affected_Mailbox" results with "Display Name User", but for some strange reason, I get the following result:
`Display Name User</Data><Data>S-1-x-11111-1111-2222-2222`

The bold part should NOT be there...
Can anyone guide me towards a working solution here?  (ps: I'm using regex101.com to 'tune' my queries).

Thanks a lot
Danny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing about writing regex queries is to specify *which* of several not-quite-compatible regex flavours is being used. It's not entirely clear from your question whether the *regex itself* goes into Splunk, or whether it's given to something like PowerShell instead. (It really doesn't matter where the *output* goes!)

But it seems that Splunk itself uses the "PCRE" (Perl-style) regex syntax, and .NET (PS) also claims to be mostly Perl-compatible, so the answer should be the same in both cases.

In PCRE regexes (and indeed all flavors currently available in Regex101), you can combine the `+` operator with `?` to mark it as "non-greedy", e.g. `.+?` will match as little as possible.

With regex flavors which do not support this feature (e.g. POSIX regular expressions), you would instead replace the `.` with a bracket expression which explicitly excludes the "boundary" character. For example, if you only want to match up to the next `<`, you would use `[^<]+` instead of `.+`.

Comment: Great! 
<Affected_Mailbox>[^<]+)
>> changed it to this query and it works in the regex101 AND in spunk.  Great great great :)